# Graphdb's loadrdf tool loads ontology and data very slow

Tags: graphdb

I am using GraphDB loadrdf tool to load an ontology and a fairly big data. I set pool.buffer.size=800000 and jvm -Xmx to 24g. I tried both parallel and serial modes. They both slow down once the repo total statements go over about 10k. It eventually slows down to 1 or 2 statements/second. Does anyone know if this is a normal behavior of loadrdf or there's a way to optimize the performance?

*Edit* I have increased tuple-index-memory. See part of my repo ttl configuration:

```
owlim:entity-index-size "45333" ; 
owlim:cache-memory "24g" ; 
owlim:tuple-index-memory "20g" ; 
owlim:enable-context-index "false" ; 
owlim:enablePredicateList "false" ; 
owlim:predicate-memory "0" ;  
owlim:fts-memory "0" ; 
owlim:ftsIndexPolicy "never" ; 
owlim:ftsLiteralsOnly "true" ; 
owlim:in-memory-literal-properties "false" ; 
owlim:transaction-mode "safe" ; 
owlim:transaction-isolation "true" ; 
owlim:disable-sameAs "true";
```

But somehow the process still slows down. It starts with "Global average rate: 1,402 st/s". But slows down to "Global average rate: 20 st/s" after "Statements in repo: 61,831". I give my jvm: -Xms24g -Xmx36g

Answer (score 1):

can you please post your repository configuration? Inside it, there is a parameter *tuple-index-memory* - this will determine the amount of changes(disc pages) that we are allowed to keep in memory. The bigger this value is the smaller amount of flushes we are going to do.

Check if this is set to a value like 20G in your setup and retry the process again.

Comment: Hi @nikolavp, thank you so much! Below please see the ttl repo configuration (I have increased tuple-index-memory). But somehow the process still slows down. It starts with "Global average rate: 1,402 st/s". But slows down to "Global average rate: 20 st/s" after "Statements in repo: 61,831". I give my jvm: -Xms24g -Xmx36g.

Comment: Part of my repo ttl: `owlim:entity-index-size "45333" ; owlim:cache-memory "24g" ; owlim:tuple-index-memory "20g" ; owlim:enable-context-index "false" ; owlim:enablePredicateList "false" ; owlim:predicate-memory "0" ; owlim:fts-memory "0" ; owlim:ftsIndexPolicy "never" ; owlim:ftsLiteralsOnly "true" ; owlim:in-memory-literal-properties "false" ; owlim:transaction-mode "safe" ; owlim:transaction-isolation "true" ; owlim:disable-sameAs "true";`

Comment: One thing I noticed from windows task manager - the CPU goes very high to almost 100% busy. But the memory usage is as low as about 11GB, although I set jvm up to 36g and cache-memory to 24g. Can you tell anything is blocking the memory use?

Comment: @cwen next time can you please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39024549/edit) to add these details, instead of commenting on the answer? Formatted text is very hard to read in comments, and besides the comment system is not really intended for ongoing discussion. I've done it for you this time around so you see how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked at you repository configuration ttl. There is this parameter: **entity-index-size=45333** whose value needs to be increased, e.g. set it to 100 million (entity-index-size=100000000). Default value for that parameter in GraphDB 7 is 10M, but since you've set it explicitly it gets overriden.

You can read more about that parameter [here](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/configuring-a-repository.html?highlight=entity%20index%20size#configuring-a-repository-configuration-parameters-entity-index-size)

Comment: Hi @Venelin, thank you very much. I have tried that - changed the parameter owlim:entity-index-size "100000000". Still very slow for both serial and parallel mode. It goes down to " Global average rate: 15 st/s" after "Statements in repo: 87,931". The memory usage stayed around 12~13GB which is very odd. Any other parameters I can tweak?